# Where does Music.app store album art?

Tags: macos, music, filesystem, metadata

I'd like to export the artwork images for adding to my collection on the new laptop.

I have a very esoteric music collection and I recently got a new Mac. I spent a fair amount of time with my old one manually setting my album art (because none of it gets populated correctly via "import album art") by right-clicking the file and using the artwork tab of "Get info".

When I moved my music to the new Mac it did not preserve my selections for artwork (I thought the image was embedded in the file metadata, but #whateves).

Where are the images actually stored?

Answer (score 6):

It took a lot of digging, but (at least in Monterey) it's in

`$HOME/Library/Containers/com.apple.AMPArtworkAgent/Data/Documents/artwork`

While that folder is hidden you can open the terminal and then use

`open ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.AMPArtworkAgent/Data/Documents/artwork`

To open the folder in Finder.

Comment: Nice + shift command G is a hidden gem for quick finder navigation. https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/go-directly-to-a-specific-folder-on-mac-mchlp1236/mac

Comment: @bmike thanks! That's a handy shortcut I didn't know.

Comment: Yup, always been in OSX's 'Go' menu from the beginning.

Comment: Same location in macOS Sonoma (14.0)